# Entity Frame Work Inserting and updating records , Preventing repeat insert in associated objects

Tags: relational-database

M working with Entity Frame Work , Inserting a new record in some secondary table first inserts record into its primary table , gets the new RowID and then inserts into the secondary table .... ok this is fine .... but not in every situation .... sometimes I do not want this functionality ... but dont know how to prevent from it ....

For Example :

**Table1**: PartId ,PartName, VendorID

**Table2**:VendorID, VendorName

Table1 and Table2 are associated with VendorID key ... when I insert some record in Table1 , EF first inserts a new row into Table2 , gets RowID (VendonID) ... and then inserts into Table1 ...

similar is the case with update Command

when I update in some secondary table , EF first unnecessarily inserts a new Row into the Primary Table , gets the New Row ID , and then updates into the Secondary Table ....

Comment: for more specification , m working at MVC , strongly typed Model View.. using Mapper class to map between entities and Models ... if some entity is is associated with another , then my model class also has a property for that object ... 
for example Talbe1 has property Vendor ... and table2 has property List<Parts> ....

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/11/06/foreign-key-relationships-in-the-entity-framework.aspx), it might help you.